# How can I listen to route change in my main App component, using a custom history object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a header that appears in 95% of pages in my site, so I mount it in my main App component. For the other 5% of pages though I need it to be gone.

I figured a good way to do it would be to change a state from true to false based on the current route, and that state would determine whether the header mounts or not.

at first I tried just using `window.location.href` as a `useEffect` dependency but that didn't seem to work. I've read about the option to listen to the location of the history, but I keep getting `Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`. I thing that perhaps it's because I am using a custom history component, or maybe because I try to do so in my main App component? Not sure.

This is my history object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; 
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

I use it in my `Router` like this:

```
<Router history={history}>

CONDITIONAL COMPONENT

  <Switch>
    ...routes
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

This is how I try to listen, where `history` is my custom history object
      const MyHistory = useHistory(history)

```
  useEffect(() => {
      return MyHistory.listen((location) => {
          console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`)
      })
  },[MyHistory])
```

Comment: Are your routes defined in App component?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes, where I've written `...routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use useHistory within a component that renders `Router` which is a Provider. In order for useHistory to Work it needs to have a Router higher up in the hierarchy.

So either you wrap the App component with Router like

```
export default () => (
    <Router history={history}><App /><Router>
)
```

or since you define a custom history you can use it directly without using useHistory

```
useEffect(() => {
      return history.listen((location) => {
          console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`)
      })
  },[])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I control every route change in my App. I created a component that listen to the `pathname` property given by [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AppScrollTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`You changed the page to: ${pathname}`)
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Then I put the component inside the `<Router>`

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <AppScrollTop />
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I hope this helps.